# XSLT Create Subtags from Metadata

Tags: xml, xslt

not sure if metadata is the correct terminology but I couldn't find a better descriptor. I have an XML that I need to transform in a few ways, but I need help with the `ENTINFO` tags specifically. What I'd like to do, is create a base tag called `ENTINFO` and then within that have each ENTINFO tag be a separate sub-field.

I have an XSLT written for the other transformations, but it's from back when I thought I didn't need the ENTINFO tags so it currently excludes them. I haven't found much in the documentation regarding how I can do what I need to do.

**Original XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NORMDOC>
   <DOC>
      <DOCID>123456789</DOCID>
      <FI fitype="B" xref="54815594127">
         <FIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</FIName>
         <FITIN>987654321</FITIN>
      </FI>
      <OIs>
         <OI xref="54815594128">
            <OIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</OIName>
         </OI>
      </OIs>
      <Subjects>
         <Subject stype="PER" xref="54815594140">
            <SubjectFullName type="L">SMITH/JANE/C</SubjectFullName>
            <SubjectLastName type="L">SMITH</SubjectLastName>
            <SubjectFirstName type="L">JANE</SubjectFirstName>
         </Subject>
      </Subjects>
      <TXT>
         <S sid="123456789-SENT-001">Refer to <ENAMEX type="BANKDIV" id="BAN-123456789-000">FCI</ENAMEX>
            <NUMEX type="CASENUM" id="CAS-123456789-001">Case # FRD-123</NUMEX>.</S>
         <S sid="123456789-SENT-075">For assistance contact <ENAMEX type="BANK" id="BAN-123456789-323">BANK OF FURY</ENAMEX> Law Enforcement Liaison at <IDEX type="PHONE" id="PHO-123456789-324">000-000-0000</IDEX> or <CYBEX type="EMAIL" id="EMA-123456789-325">email@bankoffury.com</CYBEX>.</S>
      </TXT>
   </DOC>
   <ENTINFO ID="ACC-123456789-013"
            TYPE="ACCOUNT"
            NORM="333222111000"
            REFID="ACC-123456789-013"
            ACCT-TYPE="CHK"
            MENTION="MI checking account # 333222111000"/>
   <ENTINFO ID="ACC-123456789-027"
            TYPE="ACCOUNT"
            NORM="000111222333444"
            REFID="ACC-123456789-027"
            ACCT-TYPE="UNK"
            MENTION="debit card #s 000111222333444"/>
</NORMDOC>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/NORMDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TXT">
    <RAW_TXT>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </RAW_TXT>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="extra"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="extra">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}_{@type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual Output**

```
<DOC>
   <DOCID>123456789</DOCID>
   <FI>
      <FIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</FIName>
      <FITIN>987654321</FITIN>
   </FI>
   <OIs>
      <OI>
         <OIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</OIName>
      </OI>
   </OIs>
   <Subjects>
      <Subject>
         <SubjectFullName>SMITH/JANE/C</SubjectFullName>
         <SubjectLastName>SMITH</SubjectLastName>
         <SubjectFirstName>JANE</SubjectFirstName>
      </Subject>
   </Subjects>
   <RAW_TXT>Refer to FCICase # FRD-123.For assistance contact BANK OF FURY Law Enforcement Liaison at 000-000-0000 or email@bankoffury.com.</RAW_TXT>
   <TXT>
      <S>
         <ENAMEX_BANKDIV>FCI</ENAMEX_BANKDIV>
         <NUMEX_CASENUM>Case # FRD-123</NUMEX_CASENUM>
      </S>
      <S>
         <ENAMEX_BANK>BANK OF FURY</ENAMEX_BANK>
         <IDEX_PHONE>000-000-0000</IDEX_PHONE>
         <CYBEX_EMAIL>email@bankoffury.com</CYBEX_EMAIL>
      </S>
   </TXT>
</DOC>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<DOC>
   <DOCID>123456789</DOCID>
   <FI>
      <FIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</FIName>
      <FITIN>987654321</FITIN>
   </FI>
   <OIs>
      <OI>
         <OIName>BANK OF FURY, N.A.</OIName>
      </OI>
   </OIs>
   <Subjects>
      <Subject>
         <SubjectFullName>SMITH/JANE/C</SubjectFullName>
         <SubjectLastName>SMITH</SubjectLastName>
         <SubjectFirstName>JANE</SubjectFirstName>
      </Subject>
   </Subjects>
   <RAW_TXT>Refer to FCICase # FRD-123.For assistance contact BANK OF FURY Law Enforcement Liaison at 000-000-0000 or email@bankoffury.com.</RAW_TXT>
   <TXT>
      <S>
         <ENAMEX_BANKDIV>FCI</ENAMEX_BANKDIV>
         <NUMEX_CASENUM>Case # FRD-123</NUMEX_CASENUM>
      </S>
      <S>
         <ENAMEX_BANK>BANK OF FURY</ENAMEX_BANK>
         <IDEX_PHONE>000-000-0000</IDEX_PHONE>
         <CYBEX_EMAIL>email@bankoffury.com</CYBEX_EMAIL>
      </S>
   </TXT>
</DOC>
<ENTINFO>
   <ENTINFO>
       <ENTINFO_ID>ACC-123456789-013</ENTINFO_ID>
       <ENTINFO_TYPE>ACCOUNT</ENTINFO_TYPE>
       <ENTINFO_NORM>333222111000</ENTINFO_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_REFID>ACC-123456789-013</ENTINFO_REFID>
       <ENTINFO_ACCTTYPE>CHK</ENTINFO_ACCTTYPE>
       <ENTINFO_MENTION>MI checking account # 333222111000</ENTINFO_MENTION>
   </ENTINFO>
   <ENTINFO>
       <ENTINFO_ID>ACC-123456789-027</ENTINFO_ID>
       <ENTINFO_TYPE>ACCOUNT</ENTINFO_TYPE>
       <ENTINFO_NORM>000111222333444</ENTINFO_NORM>
       <ENTINFO_REFID>ACC-123456789-027</ENTINFO_REFID>
       <ENTINFO_ACCTTYPE>UNK</ENTINFO_ACCTTYPE>
       <ENTINFO_MENTION>debit card #s 000111222333444</ENTINFO_MENTION>
   </ENTINFO>
</ENTINFO>
```

Comment: Your expected output is an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: It is not, thank you for pointing that out. I corrected it in my XSLT, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your first template to:

```
<xsl:template match="/NORMDOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC"/>
    <ENTINFO>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ENTINFO"/>
    </ENTINFO>
</xsl:template>
```

and add:

```
<xsl:template match="ENTINFO">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="ENTINFO_{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
             </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you should get the result shown in your question.